# My question is well answered, but not from any one individual answer. How best to handle/accept?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question:

[Credit card details stolen every 1-2 years. What am I doing wrong?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/111312/81248)

Which, per a recent comment, has generated a lot of very different answers.  Many of the answers have very helpful parts, but even answers with helpful parts have sections that generated a lot of disagreement or are probably even wrong (see any answer that mentions RFID blocking wallets, which isn't applicable to me anyway because my card doesn't have an RFID chip).

As a result it's making it very difficult for me to pick an answer to accept.  From my perspective, I'll probably follow advice from two different answers - use cash only in stores and use a service that hides my credit card details for online transactions.  Out of everything, these seem like the two steps that will have the most hope of minimizing future fraud.  Unfortunately, there isn't an answer that (in my opinion) brings everything together well.

As a result I'm not sure what to do.  I would like this question to have a good, solid answer for anyone who comes by in the future, but I don't feel like there is one answer that fits that bill.  The only thing I can think of is to write an answer that brings everything together.  However, since I would just be working in things from other answers, it seems unreasonable for me to write and accept such an answer myself.  Therefore I was thinking about looking into writing an answer and turning it into a community wiki if possible.  The problem with that is it still leaves the original posters with helpful answers uncredited.  Editing some of the answers seems doesn't seem like it would work either since getting a more complete answer would require substantial changes to any one answer.

> **tl/dr:** I have a question that I think is now well answered, but only
>   by taking details from many different answers.  I don't think any one
>   answer really pulls all the pieces together.  Therefore, what's the
>   best way to "accept" an answer that will be helpful for people
>   stumbling on the question later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing your own comprehensive answer and accepting it, as Ganesh suggested, is certainly a good option. You also have a couple of other good options:

- You could simply not accept any answer. The answer with the highest vote score will be at the top.
- You could accept the answer you deem to be the best of what is available, even if it is not complete. Remember that your choice is not permanent; you can unaccept the answer and/or accept a different one at any time.

The only thing accepting an answer does is put the answer you have selected at the top of the sort. If you choose not to accept any answer, nothing bad happens.

If you write your own answer and accept it, the system will not automatically sort your answer at the top; it will only be at the top if it gets the highest vote score.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with the community wiki approach. You can always upvote the other answers, but if none of them fully answers the question and you feel you can write a composite one that does, then the tick is best placed there.

Comment: I agree - it sounds like conman is looking for a way to award "partial credit" to many answers. Upvotes are effectively that tool.